# Deleting content of "/var/log/sudo-io"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, sudo, sudoers

I have a large amount of disk usage in the /var/log/sudo-io directory In the form om "AA, AB, AC..." directories

Can I delete the complete content af this directory ?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have deleted the complete contents without any ill effect.

My current cron job removes old contents a little more carefully:

```bash
# Remove files and directories older than 90 days, but not /var/log/sudo-io/ itself:
find /var/log/sudo-io/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +90 -delete
```

While this type of approach works in most cases, a situation where a script is creating tons of sudo sessions frequently will still fill the disk simply because each session creates a new directory and each directory occupies a certain minimum size (at least with `XFS`)